# NumPy array read from a .bin file is not having the same dimension when the same array was written into this file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Have written a 2D numpy array into a .bin file. Now, I want to read back this array and print it back.

This is how I did the implementation.

```py
    import numpy as np
    mat = np.array([[18, 14, 20, 17],
                    [10, 16, 10, 12],
                    [15, 21, 13, 19]])

    with open(r"D:\PythonProgram\FileHandling\Array_bin.bin", 'wb') as filer:
        print(mat,"\n")
        filer.truncate()
        filer.write(mat)

    with open(r"D:\PythonProgram\FileHandling\Array_bin.bin", 'rb') as handler:
        handler.seek(0)
        print(handler.read())

    array_data = np.fromfile(r"D:\PythonProgram\FileHandling\Array_bin.bin",dtype = int)
    print("\n",array_data)
```

```
Output:
[[18 14 20 17]
[10 16 10 12]
[15 21 13 19]]

b'\x12\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00'

[18 14 20 17 10 16 10 12 15 21 13 19]
```

When I used the method **read** method, I understood why the output is weird, since the data is per the bin file, but when `np.fromfile` is used I actually got the array elements, but this time my array got flattened.

So, is there any way to get back the array in the same dimension when it was written, but **without using the np.reshape method** ?

Comment: I guess that if you use numpy.tofile it will take care of writing the shape information.

Comment: What does the `fromfile` docs say about ahape?

Comment: Look at the np.save/load` pair. And read the docs

Comment: That method of writing does not have any dimension information.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianK. for your suggestion. It worked!

Comment: @hpaulj, Thank you! Used the `save/load` methods, it worked just like `tofile/fromfile` method suggested by @ChristianK.

Comment: `filer.write(mat)` actually writes the `mat.tostring()` to the file.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is to do with the way the file is written not the way it is read in.

Try:

```
mat = np.array([18, 14, 20, 17, 10, 16, 10, 12, 15, 21, 13, 19])
```

and then read in the file byte by byte & you will see it is exaclty the same as if you used,

```
mat = np.array([[18, 14, 20, 17],
                [10, 16, 10, 12],
                [15, 21, 13, 19]])
```

To remedy this I would suggest adding a header to your file with the relevant information or use a different method for saving.